# Execute stored procedure from c#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have c# code which executes properly on my local machine but unable to execute it on server machine.

In my code, I am calling SQL stored procedure in c# as, (c# code 1)

```
 int res = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec UpsertUser @OrgUnitId, @ExtUserId, @IntUserId, @IsTestUser, @KronosId",
                                    new SqlParameter("@OrgUnitId", Fac),
                                    new SqlParameter("@ExtUserId", id),
                                    new SqlParameter("@IntUserId", IntUserId),
                                    new SqlParameter("@IsTestUser", DBNull.Value),
                                    new SqlParameter("@KronosId", TenetId)
                                    );
                                }
```

(In above code I also tried 0 instead of DBNull.value.)
 Related stored procedure's parameter in SQL db is,

```
    ALTER procedure [dbo].[UpsertUser]
@OrgUnitId int = null,
@ExtUserId varchar(50) = null,
@IntUserId varchar(50) = null,
@IsTestUser int = NULL,
@KronosId VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
@MIPFlag TINYINT =NULL

AS
```

Both codes are also same on local and on server.

BUT, if I change the sequence of parameter in SQL db and put kronosId before IstestUser, and change stored procedure in c# to,

C# modification: code 2

```
 int res = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec UpsertUser @OrgUnitId, @ExtUserId, @IntUserId, @KronosId",
                                new SqlParameter("@OrgUnitId", Fac),
                                new SqlParameter("@ExtUserId", id),
                                new SqlParameter("@IntUserId", IntUserId),
                                new SqlParameter("@KronosId", TenetId)
                                );
```

then it works on server as well.

Am I missing something in my  c# code 1?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Usually the issue is with the connection and not the SQL statement.  Make sure you are connecting.  If not then you have a credential issue.

Comment: Hi @jdweng, thanks for responce.

Actually, I can execute other SQL queries with the same connection. Like If I change the C# code to 'C# modification: code 2'  as above then I can execute that successfully.

Comment: @user1196985 how about `(object)DbNull.Value` ?

Comment: The stored procedure has credentials and may need to be changed.  I would use SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and connect to the Server and see if you can run the stored procedure with SSMS.  The SQLParamter class has a parameter to allow Nulls. I usually define each parameter as a separate property rather than include it in the ExecuteSqlCommand and then set the allow Null property if needed.

Comment: What is the actual error you got?

Comment: Your second c# example does not contain the IsTestUser parameter, are you sure the procedure on the server is correct?

Comment: @Max, I will try the solution you mentioned,

Comment: @jdweng, I can execute stored procedure on SSMS,

Comment: @SergeyL, I am not sure about error or how to check error, I have try catch block, but it does not show any error in it.
Can you suggest me any way to check the error ( we dont have VS installed on server to check error and I can not reproduce that same error on local, because on local it works) ?

Comment: @DarrenLamb, Second code is actually working without IsTestUser, on SQL db I changed the procedure's parameter sequence and put kronosId  before IsTestUser.

Comment: SQLParameter two parameters are a string name and a type (use TypeOf(string) or TypeOf(int)).   You are using string name and value.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can get an actual error on the server if you run the sql server profiler and trace the queries to your database. As you said you have SSMS, look at the tools menu to find the profiler. You may find the failed statement and see what an actual error is.

2) My guess is that you have a type conversion issue. ExecuteSqlCommand creates its own sql statement basing in the string your provided and it declares parameters your provided (like, declare @OrgUnitId int;) in this statement. The type of variable is defined explicitly in the parameter definition or induced from the parameter value. But it is not possible if you provide null or DBNull.Value, so the default nvarchar type is used. In your case it is in contradiction with type of @IsTestUser.

Use explicit type definition for your parameters:

```
new SqlParameter("@IsTestUser", SqlDbType.Int)
        {
            Value = YouValue
        };
```

Side notes:

The best practice is to always define the type for parameters.

You can use Bit type instead of Int for this parameter.

It is better not to allow NULL for values that are logically are not null-able. 
IsTestUser should be either true or false, probably, you don't need the null value here that in this case means - I don't know. You still may have default value 0 in your database if you don't want to specify value explicitly in inserts.